# Webpack doesn't add dependencies in AngularJs using the require() method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, dependency-injection

I probably have problem with webpack configuration, because the require() method in AngularJS DI doesn't work correctly. In my app use AngularJS, Webpack and ES6.

I'm trying to add a library angular-formly-templates-bootstrap. In the source code on GitHub I see the dependency added with:

```
const ngModule = angular.module(ngModuleName, [require('angular-formly')]);
```

After installing the library using Npm in the file I can see:

```
var ngModule = angular.module(ngModuleName, [__webpack_require__(4)]);
```

Unfortunately, firing this code returns me an error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module formlyBootstrap due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module {"version":{"full":"1.6.9","major":1,"minor":6,"dot":9,"codeName":"fiery-basilisk"},"callbacks":{}} due to:
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'module' is not a function, got Object
```

I can quickly fix the error by entering the dependency name in the library code:

```
var ngModule = angular.module(ngModuleName, ['formly']);
```

At this point, everything works as it should. Obviously, this is not the right solution. The only question is why the require() method doesn't properly inject dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Require doesn't work in browser.Basically require is a node_module by which we can access other modules or files.So please if you are using it on browser side then try other things like import or self.import or injecting.

Add this to your project: [require.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.2.0/minified/require.js)

and take a look at this [Require Api](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html)

Comment: probably we have not understood each other completely. In the application I use import / export to manage files. The require() method is not from the requireJS library only from the Webpack.

Comment: possible still correcting you as webpack doesn't have any node_module or method require is a node_module.Its all done by node .